# Bootstrap inline съезжаются поля формы

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap, yii-bootstrap

Проблема с выравниванием полей в гоизонтальной форме, пример ниже.

[image: Форма]

Первая пара полей стала как надо, вторая почему то приклеелась.
эффект горизонтальной формы достигается классом **.form-inline** у родителя.

```css
.form-inline .form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

код:

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Менеджер по аренде</legend>
  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_name">Имя</label>
      <div>
        <input name="ShoppingObjectRentInfo[rental_manager_name]" id="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_name" class="input-large form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_phone">Телефон</label>
      <div>
        <input placeholder="+(380) __-___-__-__" class="input-large form-control" id="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_phone" name="ShoppingObjectRentInfo[rental_manager_phone]" type="text" maxlength="19" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_post">Должность</label>
      <div>
        <input name="ShoppingObjectRentInfo[rental_manager_post]" id="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_post" class="input-large form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_email">E-mail</label>
      <div>
        <input placeholder="example@domain.com" name="ShoppingObjectRentInfo[rental_manager_email]" id="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_email" class="input-large form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Если кто стыкался, подскажите в чем может быть подвох.

**UPD:** Версия Bootstrap - 3.3.5

Comment: Уточните браузер и версию BS. Для bs3.1.1 все выглядит хорошо.

Comment: Версия BS - 3.3.5

Comment: Какая-то наведенка в рендеринге или Смотрите в стилях выше через инструменты разработчика кто портит. Все также без слипания вижу http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojwYPd

Answer (score 1):

Судя по http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojwYPd приведенный вами код правильный. Ошибку в таких случаях ищут через инструменты разработчика.

```css
.form-inline .form-group {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<fieldset>
  <legend>Менеджер по аренде</legend>
  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_name">Имя</label>
      <div>
        <input name="ShoppingObjectRentInfo[rental_manager_name]" id="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_name" class="input-large form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_phone">Телефон</label>
      <div>
        <input placeholder="+(380) __-___-__-__" class="input-large form-control" id="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_phone" name="ShoppingObjectRentInfo[rental_manager_phone]" type="text" maxlength="19" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_post">Должность</label>
      <div>
        <input name="ShoppingObjectRentInfo[rental_manager_post]" id="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_post" class="input-large form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_email">E-mail</label>
      <div>
        <input placeholder="example@domain.com" name="ShoppingObjectRentInfo[rental_manager_email]" id="ShoppingObjectRentInfo_rental_manager_email" class="input-large form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня возникала такая проблема и она оказалась связана с отсутствием разделителя (пробела, табуляции, перевода строки) между блоками form-group. 
Вот пример, который выдает склеенные блоки (см. 4 строку):

```
<form id="loginForm" class="navbar-form navbar-right enter">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control" name="Email" placeholder="E-mail" title="" data-original-title="Введите E-mail в правильном формате">
</div><div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control" name="Password" placeholder="Пароль" title="" data-original-title="Пароль должен быть длиннее 5 символов">
</div>
</form>
```

А вот тот же пример, но блоки уже будут разделены как надо:

```
<form id="loginForm" class="navbar-form navbar-right enter">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control" name="Email" placeholder="E-mail" title="" data-original-title="Введите E-mail в правильном формате">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" data-toggle="tooltip" class="form-control" name="Password" placeholder="Пароль" title="" data-original-title="Пароль должен быть длиннее 5 символов">
</div>
</form>
```

То же касается вставки html-кода с помощью html() jQuery.